# approximation of holomorphic functions on a halfplane.

Tags: cv.complex-variables, approximation-theory

Let $\mathbb {C} _ + $ denote the right halfplane and $A$ the algebra
$$
   A = \{ f \in H^\infty({\mathbb C} _ +) \cap C(\overline{{\mathbb C} _ +}): \;
    |f(z)| \le M (1+|z|)^{-\epsilon} \text{ for some } \epsilon > 0, M > 0 \}
$$
Assume $f \in A$ and $(f_n) \subset A$ an approximating sequence with respect to sup norm, 
i.e. $\sum_{\Re(z)>0} | f_n(z) - f(z) | \to 0$.

Is there a chance that the decay rates of the approximating functions $f_n$ are uniform, i.e.
$\exists \epsilon, M>0 \forall n:\; |f_n(z)| \le M (1+|z|)^{-\epsilon} $?

Answer (score 1):

I seem unable to repair a Tex issue. In dispair I put the question again. Let $C_+$ denote the right halfplane and $A$ the algebra
$$
   A = \{ f \in H^\infty(C_+) \cap C(\bar{C_+}): \;
    |f(z)| \le M (1+|z|)^{-\epsilon} \text{ for some } \epsilon>0, M>0\}
$$
Assume $f \in A$ and $(f_n) \subset A$ an approximating sequence with respect to sup norm, 
i.e. $\sum_{\Re(z)>0} | f_n(z) - f(z) | \to 0$.

Is there a chance that the decay rates of the approximating functions $f_n$ are uniform, i.e.
$\exists \epsilon, M>0 \forall n:\; |f_n(z)| \le M (1+|z|)^{-\epsilon} $?

Comment: @ Eric: To fix the TeX problem type $\epsilon$ instead of $\eps$.  I also think  that instead of  {\mathbb C}  you should write \mathbb{C}  between  dollar signs $\mathbb{C}$.   In any case I had difficulties with TeX this morning. 

Comment: also, some space around the underscore and the > sign makes things more stable : \mathbb{C} _ + and M > 0 

Comment: +1 for TeX dispair.

Answer (score 0):

No, and a counterexample is given by $f_n(z) = \frac 1 n (1+z)^{-1/n}$. Indeed, $f_n$ converges to $0$ in sup norm, and the best $\epsilon$ in the decay rate of $f_n$ is $1/n$, which goes to $0$.